# Running Docker inside Docker container: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I created a Dockerfile to run Docker inside Docker:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - &&\
    apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" && \
   apt-get update && \
   apt-get install -y docker-ce && \
   systemctl enable docker
```

After I launched my container and ran `docker ps`, I got:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"
```

I executed the command `dockerd` inside my container, here's the result:

```
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: 
failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

Comment: How did you launched the container? Using privileged mode? Binding host's docker sock file to a volume?

Comment: [The canonical advice](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) is "don't do that".  This is a tricky and advanced configuration that's almost never necessary.

Comment: First i created an image using using the docker build and after that i ran it with docker run -it myimage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to run a Docker container inside an other Docker container, you should use already existing images provided by Docker (https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) instead of creating your own base image : choose images tagged as `dind` (**d**ocker **in** **d**ocker) or `<docker_version>-dind` (like `18.09.0-dind`). If you want to run your own image (not recommended though), don't forget to run it with `--privileged` option (that's why you get the error).

Example with `docker` official images :

```
# run Docker container running Docker daemon
docker run --privileged --name some-docker -d docker:18.09.0-dind

# run hello-world Docker image inside the Docker container previously started
docker exec -i -t some-docker docker run hello-world
```

Nevertheless, I agree with @DavidMaze comment and the reference blog post he referred to ([Do not use Docker-in-Docker for CI](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)) : Docker-in-Docker should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: I needed the following two arguments for it to work (-v and --privileged), e.g. docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged hello-world

Comment: You should either use `--privileged` and really run docker in docker or mount `/var/run/docker.sock` and use the host's docker daemon to start docker containers from your docker container. If `--privileged` is somehow disabled on the host, you will also get the `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock` error, which will confuse you even more ;-)

Answer (score 15):

The recommendation I received for this was to use the -v parameter in docker run to map the docker socket between containers like this:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this error if you use `RUN docker buildx` (which happens at image build time) instead of running it in an ENTRYPOINT script.