# Vertex AI docker in docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines, vertex-ai-pipeline

So I am using [kubeflow Containerized Python Components](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/components/containerized-python-components/) to create a Vertex AI training pipeline. As the last step of the pipeline, I would like to build and push a custom prediction container image using a [Custom Prediction Routine](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-prediction-routines), with the newly trained model baked in.

In the Dockerfile that creates the  component that handles this, I install and initialize Docker like so:

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y docker-ce && \
    systemctl enable docker
```

Then in the component Python code I have:

```
from google.cloud.aiplatform.prediction import LocalModel
    
local_model = LocalModel.build_cpr_model(
    str(PREDICT_CONTAINER_DIR),
    "my-docker-image",
    base_image="python:3.11",
    predictor=Predictor,
    requirements_path=str(PREDICT_CONTAINER_DIR / "requirements.txt"),
)
```

to build the prediction container image. This fails with `ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

After some searching, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062327/running-docker-inside-docker-container-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon) that seems to face a similar issue running Docker in a Docker container. However, I am not able to access the `docker run` command to pass `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` as the top answer suggests, because running the first container is handled by Vertex AI  Pipelines / KFP. I checked the component [task configurations](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/pipelines/pipeline-basics/#task-configurations) as well.

I also tried to use `docker` as the base image of the first container (running Docker in Docker), but then getting Python installed on it turned out to be a bit of a pain.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to get my prediction container deployed?

Comment: How are you launching the container that runs your Python code?  The `docker run -v` or Compose `volumes:` option would go there.  You can't run a Docker daemon as a background process in your application container; you might need the `apt-get install` command to get the `docker` CLI tool, but I'd expect the `systemctl` invocation to fail and you should delete that.

Comment: Edited -- Vertex AI Pipelines handles running the component containers. All I do is start the pipeline run. Hm ok, so I tried adding `docker-ce-cli` to the `apt-get install`. In the build it says `docker-ce` and `docker-cli` are already the latest version. For context, the output during build after `systemctl enable docker` is `Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker`, and then it says successfully built. I tried removing the `systemctl` call as well, but same end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCP support confirmed that for security reasons it is not possible to run Docker in Vertex AI Pipelines components. Docker images can be built from inside components with CloudBuild, for example via the [Python SDK](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/libraries#use).